# show an open spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have Async task to provide me list of some cities and after I have the list, I want to show me an OPEN spinner directly without any dialogs. My code opens spinner with propper list, but clickListener doesn't seems to work.

my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerCities);
    listAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    spinner.performClick();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aView, View selectedItemView,
                int position, long longID) {
                    System.out.println("ON ITEM CLICK LISTENER HERE");
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aView) {
        }
    });
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?  What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: in my case: sysout does not show

Comment: Sysout will display on selecting any item from the spinner. did you check that?

Comment: If i click on any of items, spinner closes up, but nothing else happens. Like there is no listener for any clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several hours, I figured it out. I need to use Dialog, but result is the same I have wanted. Here is source in case, someone is find useful.

```
private void MyMethod(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
            (String[])MyClass.getListOfCities().toArray());
    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setIcon(icon);
    ad.setTitle("Title");
    ad.setSingleChoiceItems( listAdapter, -1, new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            // DO something when I click on item
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ad.show();
}
```